# Is overriding a module's method a good convention?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I've got some kind of `template patterned` module with few method defined (default behaviour) and some which look like method below:

```
def tax
  1.2
end

def do_something!
  raise "Please implement it in your class"
end
```

I've read that in most cases I should use modules over inheritance because of inheritance capabilities (single inheritance) and when I don't need `super()` at all.

But I feel a bit guilty to override all `raise "..."` methods and also some default (like `tax` method), because it is module.

What do you think?

When I need to override methods should I rather use inheritance or including modules?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more code as it will make it easier to determine what pattern would be most suitable. Whether it be module inclusion, inheritance or possibly even a decorator pattern ([Nice Article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in)) is all kind of dependent on the objects themselves and how they interact.

Comment: _"I've read that in most cases I should use modules over inheritance"_ -- in my opinion, this is a **really** bad idea; sorry.  Almost everything you need to do can be done with single inheritance, and the results will be clean and readable. You will occasionally find exceptions, and for this, there are mixins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule I usually follow is: when the method has to be defined in the class including the module (e.g. module acts as an interface) i always do:

```
def method_that_needs_to_be_defined
  raise NoMethodError
end
```

It's good practice, prevents unexpected calls to yet undefined method.

Example:

```
module Speaker
  def speak
    raise NoMethodError
  end
end

class Bird < Animal
  include Speaker

  def speak
    'chirp'
  end
end
```